# Why are my post parameters not making it to my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, post

After stepping through my code, I have verified that collection.Get("username"); is null in the below code, which means my post parameters just aren't making it into the controller. Can anyone spot the problem?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Admin(uint id, FormCollection collection) {
    var username = collection.Get("username");
    var password = collection.Get("password");
    Helper.CreateUser(username,password);
    return View("AdministerUsers");
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <label for="username">username</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("username") %>
    <label for="password">password:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("password") %>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Add User" name="submitUser" />
<% } %>
```

Routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin",
    "Admin/{id}",
    new { controller = "Administration", action = "Admin"}
);
```

Comment: You have specified <label for="username">UserName</label>. Remove this line and try it again

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan - a label has no bearing on the form value.

Comment: Instead of using `Get("username")`, try `collection["username"]` instead.  It shouldn't make a difference, but i'm curious if it does.  I would suggest using Tejs solution though, rather than FormCollection as it's more type safe.

Comment: Mystere Man, that did it! Thank you so much. Such a little thing, I never would have thought to try it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the asp.net mvc way and strongly type your view to a model

Model:

```
 public class ViewModel
    {
      public string Username {get; set;}
      public string Password {get; set;}
    }
```

Strongly type your view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ViewModel>" %>  //the ViewModel will need to have it's fully qualified name here
```

Then use mvc's default model binding:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>

    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username) %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username) %>

    <%= Html.Label(m => m.Password) %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password) %>

    <input type="submit" value="Add User" name="submitUser" />
<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Admin(ViewModel model) 
{
    var username = model.Username;
    var password = model.Password;
    Helper.CreateUser(username,password);
    return View("AdministerUsers");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FormCollection doesn't have properties corresponding to Username or Password; MVC binding looks to the object using reflection to determine where posted data gets bound to.

So, in your case, switching to this signature should fix your problem:

```
 public ActionResult Admin(uint id, string username, string password)
 {
      // .. Do your stuff
 }
```

Since the parameters contain 'username' and 'password', which match the names of the form elements you are posting, the data they contain will be bound to those variables.

Comment: FormCollection doesn't need to have properties corresponding to Username or Password, it's a collection of NameValue pairs that correspond to posted values.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know, the default model binder will not stick every post value into a dictionary / hashtable just because it's on the signature, unless the post data is formatted in a specific way.

Comment: Yes, the default model binder will put every querystring or post value into `FormsCollection`.  That's the point, it's the equivalent of `Page.Request[""]`